# what is the difference between n(not running) and d(done) conditions in autosys?

Tags: autosys

I am aware that the done(d) condition would be TRUE when the job is in SU, TE, FA status. I would like to understand the same for n, and so the difference between n and d conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "notrunning" condition will be TRUE when the status of the job on which it is dependent is anything except RUNNING.

Answer (score 0):

As name suggest not running condition, it checks the job is running or not.

The  n (notrunning) condition will be TRUE when the status of the job on which it is dependent, is in any status except RU (Running).